# NLog blob storage extension with dynamic connection string

Tags: runtime, azure-blob-storage, connection-string, nlog

BlobStorage target property is not changed as I expected.

I use this code. (of course le connection string is the real azureblobstorage one)

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["simple-log-file-name"] = "simple-log.txt";
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["blob-container"] = "logs";
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["blobconst"] = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=....";
```

Target is setup in nlog.config:

```
<target xsi:type="AzureBlobStorage" name="simple-log-target" blobName="${var:simple-log-file-name}" container="${var:blob-container}" connectionString="${var:blobconst}"....
```

At this point nlog fail to setup with

> Error AzureBlobStorageTarget(Name=simple-log-target): Failed to create
> BlobClient with connectionString=. Exception:
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'connectionString')

If I put the Aure connection string in nlog config target, it works: It writes to storage defined by nlog.config in container and blob that are set in runtime.

```
<target xsi:type="AzureBlobStorage" name="simple-log-target" blobName="${var:simple-log-file-name}" container="${var:blob-container}" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=...." ...
```

Is it possible to define this connectionString at runtime at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using NLog-Configuration-Variables then try using GDC:

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("simple-log-file-name", "simple-log.txt");
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("blob-container", "logs");
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("blobconst", "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=....";
```

And setup NLog.config like this (Make sure to assign GDC-values before creating first NLog.Logger-object):

```
<target xsi:type="AzureBlobStorage" name="simple-log-target" blobName="${gdc:simple-log-file-name}" container="${gdc:blob-container}" connectionString="${gdc:blobconst}"
```

See also: [NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage - Azure ConnectionString](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/README.md#azure-connectionstring)